# Sending email to recipients with specific field from table of MySQL database using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, email, send

I am building a web-platform where visitors can ask questions to professionals which are divided into several different categories.

I have the following tables :
- 'questions' (containing the question, the visitor's email address and the category)
- 'professionals' (containing the infos, the professional's email and the category)
- 'responses' (containing the response, the question's ID and the professional's ID)

Ok, here is what I want to do :
- When the 'questions' table is updated, I want the platform to send an email to the professionals in the chosen category.

and

- when the professional answers the question, I want to send an email to the visitor.

I already get an admin email when the database is updated so I know this can be done.

B.T.W., I am novice so lots of details please !

Thanks for your help !

Ian

Comment: How do you update `questions` and `responses` tables? Just get the email addresses during that and send the emails.

Comment: other than saying "add the code to send the email on update" i'm not sure how it could be answered

Answer (score 2):

If you have a lot of professionals in the professionals table, it would be advisable to use a sort of PHP mail queueing system. Otherwise, the script may be running a long time, and never complete within the execution time frame. It's better to do it in the background (such as with a cron job that gets executed every 10 minutes or so).

Let's assume for a moment there's only two professionals.

When you update the database to insert a new question, pull a list of professionals from the category. You need to put the category of the question into a variable (like $category)

```
$results = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM professionals WHERE category=$category");
```

Now you have a result set containing the e-mails of all the professionals relevant to that category. Put all of them neatly into an array.

```
 $emails = array();
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)){
                 $emails[] = $row['email'];
     }
```

We have an array of the professionals' e-mails, now we need to e-mail them:

```
foreach($emails as $email){
        mail($email,"A new question in your category!","Text goes here");
      }
```

More information: http://php.net/mail

Comment: WoW !  This is very nice !
Thanks PseudoOne !

I guess I can reverse the process for the 'responses' table updates.

I will have over 100 professionals.  Better with a cron job, I guess !

Your help is very much appreciated ! :)

Take care !
Ian